# PythonTeX: importing python files

Tags: python, import

I'm trying to import a personal python module using python tex, but pythontex doesn't find the module. My attempt:

The LaTeX File:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pythontex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[makestderr]{pythontex}

\begin{document}

\begin{pyconsole}
import os
os.getcwd()
import sayhi
\end{pyconsole}

\end{document}
```

The Python module sayhi.py, in the same directory (/Users/christopherchudzicki/Desktop/pythontex/importproblem) as the LaTeX file:

```
def hi():
    print("hi")
```

LaTeX Output:
[image: LaTeX Output]

I'd like to be able to call sayhi.hi() from within the pyconsole environment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a bug in the `console` environments.  The current working directory isn't being added to `sys.path`.  I will fix this in the next release.

If you're using PythonTeX v0.12beta (on [GitHub](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex)) you can use the following workaround for now.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[makestderr]{pythontex}

\begin{document}

\begin{pyconcode}
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
\end{pyconcode}

\begin{pyconsole}
import sayhi
sayhi.hi()
\end{pyconsole}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this bug just in pyconsole, or in pycode, etc, also? [It doesn't work in pycode for me.]

Comment: @mrc It's a bug in everything console-related. It won't work by default in `pycode`, because even though the current working directory is added to `sys.path`, by default the current working directory is always the PythonTeX output directory, not the document root directory. That way, everything generated by PythonTeX is isolated in a single location (if you don't specify paths). If you want the document directory to be the working directory, you can use `\setpythontexworkingdir{.}`. In the next release, I will probably set things always to add the document directory to `sys.path`.

Comment: @mrc I just released PythonTeX v0.12, which incorporates the bugfix.  The `console` commands and environments will now behave like the normal ones, so far as `sys.path` is concerned.